# What's the ZSH equivalent of BASH's $PROMPT_COMMAND?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, environment-variables

BASH supports a `$PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable that defines a command to be executed before any first-level interactive prompt. I'm looking for a ZSH equilvalent of that.

[The documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html) says that there's a function `precmd` I can define to achive that; however, I have no idea how to define it from an environment variable.

I've considered passing an environment variable that would make ZSH read a file containing the definition of that function, but ZSH [doesn't seem to support such things](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Files): it only reads global files and then per-user files. I can replace them but I cannot add to them without modifying the files, which I cannot do.

So how do I define a pre-prompt hook in ZSH via an environment variable, like I'd do using `$PROMPT_COMMAND` in BASH?

Comment: Truth to be told, I need a post-interactive-command-execution hook, but neither shell provides one so I have to resort to pre-prompt hooks - they seem to be as close as I can get.

Comment: Hm, I am wondering, what the difference between _post-interactive-command-execution_ and _pre-prompt_ is. Apart from a conceptual difference, where do you observe actually a difference. (Let's omit the commands `exit` and `exec`, ok `;)` )

Comment: @mpy there's a difference when running a background job, because background jobs are independent from the prompt sequence.

Comment: Ok, I got that point. So, how about something like that: `start() { eval "$@"; echo post-command-code }` and then use a zle-binding to execute the command line with `start` prepended?

Comment: @mpy Actually there might be an even better way, here's what I found in shell options: "DEBUG_BEFORE_CMD Run the DEBUG trap before each command; otherwise it is run after each command." Looks like this is exactly what I need!

Comment: The `DEBUG` trap is a nice find, but you still have the problem how to define it. I've extended my answer once more, but I leave it to you to write your own answer regarding the DEBUG trap solution. `:)`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The simplest approach to emulate bash's `$PROMPT_COMMAND` which comes to my mind is to use the `precmd` hook, as you already figured out. Define it as

```
precmd() { eval "$PROMPT_COMMAND" }
```

and you can do something like that:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo Hello, it is now $(date)'
Hello, it is now Mon, Mar 31, 2014 7:08:00 PM
$ whoami      
user
Hello, it is now Mon, Mar 31, 2014 7:08:21 PM     
$
```

Please note the single quotes in that example, otherwise `$(date)` will get expanded too early, i.e. already when defining `$PROMPT_COMMAND` and not when called before the prompt.

---

If you want to preserve (and don't want to alter) the existing definition, you can use that approach:

```
$ prmptcmd() { eval "$PROMPT_COMMAND" }
$ precmd_functions=(prmptcmd)
```

With that the `prmptcmd` functions is executed after the existing `precmd()` function.

---

Finally, here is a way which is suitable for use in a program package, which neither should modify user or system files nor can enter the commands interactive.

An example to spawn a bash session could be

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo foo" bash
```

To spawn zsh you can use

```
ZDOTDIR=/program/dir zsh
```

which causes `/program/dir/.zshrc` to be sourced. In this file the `precmd()` hook can be defined as explained above. If you want the user's settings *in addition* include `source $HOME/.zshrc` etc. in the program's .zshrc, too.
This setup is maintainable, as no files outside the program directory are modified.

---

As a last addition, here is a proof of concept how to keep the newuser welcome, too. Use the following code in your `/program/dir/.zshenv` rc config file:

```
echo define precmd, traps, etc.

autoload -Uz zsh-newuser-install

if [[ ! -e "$HOME/.zshrc" ]]; then
  zsh-newuser-install -f
  mv $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc $HOME/.zshrc
else
  builtin source $HOME/.zshrc
fi
```

Comment: That much I figured. The problem is - how do I define the precmd hook via an environment variable? Is there a mechanism for adding hooks or code without modifying files? Or how do I do it at least without writing to the global and user-global ".zprofile" and similar files? Like, can I add my own .zprofile that won't replace existing ones?

Comment: Also your use of precmd hook here would replace any alread existing precmd hooks; zsh docs mention I can make an array of functions that will coexist but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: (1) What do you mean with _how do I define the precmd hook via an environment variable?_ The example I presented works IMHO like bash mechanism. (2) You can add the hook via command-line, but then it's not permanent. What's the problem with the modification of your `.zshrc`? (3) An example: `foo() { echo foo }; bar() { echo bar }; precmd_functions=(foo bar)` This executes `foo()` and `bar()` _in addition_ to `precmd()`.

Comment: It's supposed to be used internally from an application that spawns the shell. I'd very much prefer avoiding modifying the user's .zshrc because I don't want any side effects on shells spawned from regular terminal. Also modifying .zshrc makes installation and clean removal of the program really tricky. Can I define my own precmd hook without modifying the system- or user-wide files?

Comment: Ok, that clarifies a lot -- a minimal example for bash would then be `PROMPT_COMMAND="echo foo" bash`, right? Is this a possibility for spawning zsh: `ZDOTDIR=/program/dir zsh`. Then `/program/dir/.zshrc` is sourced upon start where you can define the precmd() hook. If you want the user's in addition include `source $HOME/.zshrc` etc. in the program's zshrc. This should be easy to maintain, as no files outside the program dir are modified.

Comment: @Shnatsel : I extended my answer. Perhaps you can also edit your question to include the additional info from your comments.

Comment: Uh, turns out that still isn't sufficient because zsh has a welcome function what writes out .zshrc - which will not be triggered if I override ZDOTDIR. And I don't want to break the welcome because without it the shell is really barebones and not what the user expects. Maybe there's a way to trigger it manually if the file does not exist or something along those lines?

Answer (score 13):

As @mypy states, Zsh's `precmd` works similarly to Bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Here's an example that works for Bash or Zsh and doesn't use `eval`:

```
## ~/myprompt.sh

# 'ZSH_VERSION' only defined in Zsh
# 'precmd' is a special function name known to Zsh

[ ${ZSH_VERSION} ] && precmd() { myprompt; }

# 'BASH_VERSION' only defined in Bash
# 'PROMPT_COMMAND' is a special environment variable name known to Bash

[ ${BASH_VERSION} ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=myprompt

# function called every time shell is about to draw prompt
myprompt() {
  if [ ${ZSH_VERSION} ]; then
    # Zsh prompt expansion syntax
    PS1='%{%F{red}%}%n%{%f%}@%{%F{red}%}%m %{%F{cyan}%}%~ %{%F{white}%}%# %{%f%}'
  elif [ ${BASH_VERSION} ]; then
    # Bash prompt expansion syntax
    PS1='\[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[31m\]\h \[\e[36m\]\w \[\e[37m\]\$ \[\e[0m\]'
  fi
}
```

Run from shell init scripts:

```
## ~/.bashrc
. ~/myprompt.sh
```

and:

```
## ~/.zshrc
. ~/myprompt.sh
```

The prompts here are just examples.  One can definitely do much trickier stuff.

For details of setting prompt functions, see: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-precmd and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt.

For details of prompt expansions, see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt.